# Variants of Parseval's relation

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Let us consider a $2 \pi-$periodic function $U(x)$. From [Parseval's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem), I have the relation
$$
\sum_{k} |U_{k}|^{2} = \int_{- \pi}^{\pi} \!\! \frac{\mathrm{d} x}{2 \pi} \, |U (x)|^{2} \, ,
$$
where the Fourier coefficients are defined as
$$
U_{k} = \int_{\pi}^{\pi} \!\! \frac{\mathrm{d} x}{2 \pi} \, \mathrm{e}^{- \mathrm{i} k x} U (x) \, . 
$$
One virtue of Parseval's Theorem is that it allows me to compute the sum $\sum_{k} |U_{k}|^{2}$ by only computing one integral, without having to determine all the individual Fourier coefficients.

Now, I want to estimate a slightly different sum, given by
$$
\sum_{k} |k| |U_{k}|^{2}
$$
It is possible to write down a variant of Parseval's Theorem, so as to rewrite in a simple manner this sum?

Comment: I can see a way to get $\Sigma k^2 \vert U_k \vert^2$ , by differentiating the original series.

Comment: @AlexPavellas Yes, I agree with you, one has to note that the Fourier coefficients of ${ V(x) = U'(x) }$ are $V_{k} = \mathrm{i} k U_{k}$, and apply Parseval's theorem for $V(x)$.